# Calculating cumulative sum

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to display bar graph that has the cumulative sum of Panels for a week. Then after the week it refreshes starts again for the next week. We are using Date completed column to figure out the week.

For eg.
week 1:
1st nov - 10 panels are produced 
2nd nov - 10 panels are produced (the bar graph would have 20 panels for 2nd nov)
3rd nov - 10 panels are produced (the bar graph would have 30 panels for 3rd nov)

I was able to calculate the cumulative sum using the below formula

`Cumulative_Panels = 
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        Query1,
        WEEKNUM ( Query1[TDATE] )
            = WEEKNUM ( EARLIER ( Query1[TDATE]) )
            && Query1[TDATE] <= EARLIER ( Query1[TDATE] )
    ),
    Query1[Units]
)`
This is what i get

[image]

Everything is good but the only problem is that the week starts from sunday. As you can see, i want 11/05/2017 to be part of week1 and the new week should start from monday 11/06/2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WEEKNUM` has a parameter where you can set which day the week begins.
If you want the week to start from Monday, you can change your `WEEKNUM` function to:

```
WEEKNUM(Query1[TDATE], 2) = WEEKNUM(EARLIER(Query1[TDATE]), 2)
```

where `2` is the parameter I'm talking about.

---

Details reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634572.aspx).

```
WEEKNUM(<date>, <return_type>)
```

return_type: A number that determines the return value: use 1 when the week begins on Sunday; use 2 when the week begins on Monday. The default is 1.